# Prove a stronger version of the pumping lemma for context-free languages

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma

Let $L$ be a context-free language. Prove that there exists integer $p>0$ such that

$ \forall z\in L $ such that $ |z|\ge p $, there exists a partition $ z=uvwxy $ such that

1. $|vwx|\le p$
2. $|vx|\geq2$
3. $\forall i\geq 0 : uv^iwx^iy\in L$

HINT: $p$ needs to be bounded $ p\leq 2^{2k}$ which gives you more power. What is the power?

---

Please note the constraint $|xv|\geq2$ is stronger than the constraint $|xv|>0$ in the usual pumping lemma of context-free languages. How I can prove from one to another please?

Comment: This is a well-known question. Note that there is a mistake in step $II$ of the claim, it must be $|vx|>0$ and not as you've stated, that is $v$ or $x$ can be empty but not both of them. You could've reached a proper proof easily by just searching on google, here is a link that could help you: https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/cs373/sp2013/Lectures/lec17.pdf

Comment: hay whats up , i need the help on the version i wrote specificly , maybe can you give me a hint? how to go from the famous version to this version?

Comment: Downvoters and the first commenter did not realize this question is about **a stronger version** of the usual pumping lemma. Please upvote this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Proof Idea for the usual pumping lemma

Let $z$ be a very long string in $L$. A parse tree for $z$ is so tall that it must contain some long path from the start symbol at the root of the tree to
one of the terminals at a leaf. On this long path, some nonterminal $R$ must repeat because of the pigeonhole principle. This repetition of a nonterminal allows us to replace the subtree under the second occurrence of $R$ with the subtree under the first occurrence of $R$, which leads to a parse tree of a new string in $L$. We can thus find a partition $z=uvwxy$ where $vx$ is nonempty and $v...x$ can be pumped.

##### Refined Idea

To extend the length of the pumpable part to be $\ge2$, we will let $z$ be even longer so that some nonterminal $R$ must appear at least three times so that we can find a partition $z=uv_1v_2wx_2x_1y$ where both $v_1x_1$ and $v_2x_2$ are nonempty and $v_1x_1...x_2v_2$ can be pumped.

##### Proof

Here is a proof that follows basically the proof in *Introduction to the Theory of Computation* by Michael Sipser.

Let $G$ be a Chomsky normal form grammar for $L$. In any parse tree using $G$, a node can have no more than $2$ children. So, if the height of the parse tree is at most $h$, the length of the string generated is at most $2^h$.

Say $k$ is the number of non-terminals in $G$. We set $p$, the pumping length, to be $2^{2k+1}$. Now if $z$ is a string in $L$ and  its length is $p$ or more, its parse tree must be at least $2k+1$ high, because $2^{2k+1}\gt2^{2k}$.

Let $\tau$ be one of its parse tree. If $z$ has several parse trees, choose $\tau$ to be a parse tree that has the smallest number of nodes. We know that $\tau$ must be at least $2k+1$ heigh, so its longest path from the root to a leaf has length at least $2k+1$. That path has at least $2k+2$ nodes; one at a terminal, the others at non-terminals. Hence that path has at least $2k+1$ non-terminals.

Consider the first $2k+1$ non-terminals on that path starting from the root. With $G$ having only $k$ non-terminals, some non-terminal $R$ appears at least $3$ times among them, thanks to the pigeon-hole principle.

[image: pumping lemma for context-free languages]

We divide $z$ into $uvwxy$, where $v=v_1v_2$ and $x=x_2x_1$ according to the figure above, which depicts the parse tree of $z$ as selected above. If we ignore the middle occurrence of $R$, $R$ still repeats. We can continue the usual proof of the usual pumping lemma to obtain that $|vx|\ge1$, $|vwx|\le p$ and $uv^iwx^iy\in L$ for all $i\ge0$.

Suppose both $v_1$ and $x_1$ were empty. The parse tree obtained by substituting the subtree rooted at the middle occurrence of $R$ for the subtree rooted at the upper occurrence of $R$ would have fewer nodes than $\tau$ does and would still generate $z$. This result isn't possible because we had already chosen $\tau$ to be a parse tree for $z$ with the smallest number of nodes. Hence either $v_1$ or $x_1$ is non-empty. Similarly, either $v_2$ or $x_2$ is non-empty. So $vx=v_1v_2x_2v_2$ must have length at least $2$.

Comment: thank you a lot !!!

Comment: You are welcome!